# QtQuick / QML: Reparenting an item to the last cell of a GridLayout does not work

Tags: qml, qtquick2

In my application I want to manually place elements in a GridLayout and move them between cells by drag and drop, just like a chessboard. I do this by manually setting the parent of the element to be placed to the cell index. I found this approach in another post and I like it very much.
To explain my problem I have put together a minimal working example.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 100
    visible: true

    GridLayout{
        columns: 10

        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        Repeater{
            model: 10 * 2

            Rectangle{
                color: "lightblue"
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
        }

    }

    Text{
        property int cellidx: 1
        parent: grid.children[cellidx]
        font.pointSize: 18
        font.bold: true
        text: cellidx
    }

    Text{
        property int cellidx: 18
        parent: grid.children[cellidx]
        font.pointSize: 18
        font.bold: true
        text: cellidx
    }

    Text{
        property int cellidx: 19
        parent: grid.children[cellidx]
        font.pointSize: 18
        font.bold: true
        text: cellidx
    }
}
```

In principle, this already works quite well. Except for the last cell of the GridLayout. As you can see in the screenshot placing the `Text` element to the last cell does not work

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLaUa.png)

When trying to place an element to the last cell by using`parent: grid.children[cellidx]` with `cellidx` = index of the last cell, it alway is placed in or near the very first cell of the layout.

I also tried `Grid` for the layout, but have observed the same effect there. Maybe someone has an idea for this beginner problem. Google could not help me either unfortunately. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grid.children` may contain objects other than the Rectangles you've added. There may be internally created children as well. When I tested your code, I could add text to the last rect by parenting to `grid.children[20]` instead of `grid.children[19]`.

Comment: Indeed, the Repeater component is an Item so it will show up in children of the GridLayout also.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess This hint helped me. Then the repeater is not the right method in my case to place elements and address them by means of continuous index.

Comment: @matthoe1212 Repeater.itemAt() should do the trick for you.